# Chrooted SFTP user can't login

Tags: ssh, chroot

I'm trying to configure a user who will only be able to access to an specific directory. I've configured a Chroot jail in SSH and changed its home directory, but configuring the internal-sftp with chroot the user can't login through sftp client.

**SSH config**

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

        Match Group sftpusers
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/latama
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTCPForwarding no
```

I've did adduser latama sftpusers, to join latama to sfrpusers group.

Changed it's /etc/passwd to

```
latama:x:1002:1003:,,,:/var/www/latama:/bin/nologin
```

**Directory permissions**

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 latama www-data       4096 Nov  5 08:33 latama
```

And when I try to connect through sftp happens this with verbose mode activated.

```
latama@ourdomain.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to ourdomain.com ([175.75.145.125]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to ourdomain.com closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 1760, received 2316 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 812187.8, received 1068765.3
debug1: Exit status -1
Connection closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chroot folder needs to be owned by root, and the write bit should only be set for the owner.

Comment: Thanks!, It worked fine